# showing all users post on Admin Login

Tags: laravel

```
public function index()
{
   $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
   $user = User::find($user_id);
   $leave_request_form = leave_request_form::all();
   return view('leave_request_form/index')->with('leave_request_form', $user->leave_request_form);
}
```

How do I make an admin view all user posts?

Comment: You need to explain what you're asking. What are user posts? I dont see anything like that in your code.

Comment: Well, I created a leave request form and added a user_id column to both the leave request form and the User tables. I used @can to enable users see only the leave request form. Admin can also see the leave request form. The code above enables users and admin see only their leave request they created. Now I want the admin logged in to be able to view all the requests from all the users.  I hope my question is clear now. Thanks